# How to get value and store it in a variable from a line edit or text edit in pyQT?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

How to get value and store it in a variable (in main python plugin) from a line edit or text edit box that were created in QT designer ?

Comment: probably you should add more info... with what GIS? may you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the text like so:

```
text = self.your_plugin_dlg.ui.yourLineEdit.text()
```